# Git checkout and remote tracking misunderstood

Tags: git

I need explanations about Git which is a bit new for me.

I come from old school SVN where everyone hurry up to commit to remote repository to not have conflicts you know .... This time is finished :).

Well, I did three commands with git :

1)

```
C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>git checkout -b fflbranche origin/dev-17.5-tma
Switched to a new branch 'fflbranche'
Branch fflbranche set up to track remote branch dev-17.5-tma from origin.

C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>git status
On branch fflbranche
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev-17.5-tma'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        crf-fra-core/src/main/documentation/diagramme.vpp.bak_000f
        crf-fra-core/src/main/documentation/diagramme.vpp.vbak
        crf-fra-core/src/main/documentation/diagramme.vux
        crf-fra-eshop-fo/src/main/documentation/diagrammes.vpp.bak_000f
        crf-fra-eshop-fo/src/main/documentation/diagrammes.vpp.vbak
        crf-fra-eshop-fo/src/main/documentation/diagrammes.vux
        src/main/documentation/Architecture.vpp.bak_000f
        src/main/documentation/Architecture.vpp.vbak
        src/main/documentation/Architecture.vux

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>
```

2)

```
C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>git branch --list
  dev-17.5
  dev-17.5-art04
* fflbranche
  master
  origin/dev-17.5

C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>
```

3)

```
C:\webs\carrefour-france\crf-fra>git remote show origin
Username for 'http://kazan.priv.atos.fr': a665145
Password for 'http://a665145@kazan.priv.atos.fr':
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://kazan.priv.atos.fr/git/crf-fra
  Push  URL: http://kazan.priv.atos.fr/git/crf-fra
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    17.2-eligibilite           tracked
    dev-15.3.2-optimAdmin      tracked
    dev-16.0.1                 tracked
    dev-16.1-old               tracked
    ...(much more)
    stable-17.3-monitoringSF   tracked
    stable-17.3.1              tracked
    stable-CONF-ENV            tracked
    tmp-trunk                  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    dev-17.5       merges with remote dev-17.5
    dev-17.5-art04 merges with remote dev-17.5-art04
    fflbranche     merges with remote dev-17.5-tma
    master         merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev-17.5       pushes to dev-17.5       (local out of date)
    dev-17.5-art04 pushes to dev-17.5-art04 (up to date)
    master         pushes to master         (local out of date)
```

My question is :

Why in last output, in "Local refs configured for 'git push':" part it doesn't appear "fflbranche". Does it means that if I modify a file on this local branche, I can't push it to remote tracked branche ?

Thanks for your lights !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why in last output, in "Local refs configured for 'git push':" part it doesn't appear "fflbranche"

I guess you have not Pushed to remote yet so, git did not save it. You obviously can push to remote from `fflbranche` branch.

```
$ git checkout fflbranche
// do changes & commit

$ git push -u origin fflbranche       
# -u = --set-upstream tells git to remember the parameters, so that next time you can simply run 'git push'

$ git remote show origin
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right, I didn't push yet.

Answer (score 0):

Git branches are lazy, and git doesn't create a local branch unless you command it to do so.

Normally, a `git checkout` will initialize a branch with the remote state, and sets the tracking status properly.

If you want to push a branch isn't tracked (this is often new branch), setting origin also works:

```
git push --set-upstream origin "$(git-branch-current 2> /dev/null)"
```

You have multiple pushable remotes, so you would also like to replace `origin` with the remote you want.